# Regex to detect if a text is between two parenthesis (herringbones) with no space after and before

Tags: regex

```
"a <a bc> de"     # TRUE
"a <<a bc>> de"   # TRUE
"a <a bc> >de"    # TRUE
"a <<a bc> de"    # TRUE
"a < a bc> de"    # FALSE
"a <a bc > de"    # FALSE
"a <<a bc >> de"  # FALSE
"a <a bc >> de"   # FALSE
```

I tried the following one :

```
regex = "<+\S.*\S]>+"
```

Comment: You may use: `<+[^\s\<>](?:[^<>]*[^\s<>])?>+`

Comment: What about `a <<a bc> de` and `a <>a bc> de`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `a <<a bc> de` TRUE

Comment: Then use [`<+[^<>\s](?:[^<>]*[^\s<>])?>+`](https://regex101.com/r/rpAJBv/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's the same as @anubhava?

Comment: He edited his regex to mine, so yes. He had `<+\S` in the beginning, so I had to ask for clarification. Note you do not need to escape `<` and `>`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It was edited right after posting comment, probably you didn't refresh your browser.

Comment: Can you add it as an answer and explain it, especially the `?`?

Comment: What about if I want `"a <>a bc> de" # TRUE`

Comment: @Julien: In my answer below I have addressed `a <>a bc> de` case as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex:

```bash
<+[^\s<](?:[^<>]*[^\s<>])?>+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ye0UKN/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `<+`: Match 1+ of `<` characters
- `[^\s<]`: Match any char that is not a whitespace and not a `<`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[^<>]*`: Match 0 or more of any char that is not `<` and `>`
  - `[^\s<>]`: Match any char that is not a whitespace and not `<` and `>`
- `)?`: End non-capture group. `?` makes this group *optional*
- `>+`: Match 1+ of `>` characters